# Error en formulario de contacto no se envia

Tags: javascript

Tengo este formulario en js:

```
function submitContacto() {
    var condiciones = $("#condiciones_form").is(':checked');
    var form_completo = ($("#nombre_from").val() != "") && ($("#email_from").val() != "") && ($("#delegacion_from").val() != "") && ($("#empresa_from").val() != "") && ($("#telefono_from").val() != "") && ($("#poblacion_form").val() != "") && ($("#comentarios_form").val() != "");
    if (condiciones && form_completo) {
        var formFields = $("#formContacto").serializeArray();
        var formData = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < formFields.length; i++) {
            formData = formData + "&" + formFields[i].name + "=" + formFields[i].value;
        }
        formData = formData.substring(1);
        $("#formContacto button[type='submit']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#formContacto .formResponse").addClass("loading").removeClass("ok").removeClass("error").html(LANG_ENVIANDO);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contact.php",
            data: formData
        }).done(function(data) {
            if (data == "0") {
                $("#formContacto .formResponse").html(LANG_ENVIADO_OK).addClass("ok");
            } else {
                $("#formContacto .formResponse").html(LANG_ENVIADO_ERROR).addClass("error");
            }
            $("#formContacto .formResponse").removeClass("loading");
            $("#formContacto button[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
        });
    } else {
        if (!condiciones && form_completo)
            $("#formContacto .formResponse").html(LANG_DEBE_ACEPTAR).addClass("error");
        else
            $("#formContacto .formResponse").html(LANG_DEBE_COMPLETAR).addClass("error");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Cuando valida el var form_completo sale el mensaje de LANG_ENVIADO_ERROR el cual no se por que lo printea y todos los campos están validados y están bien

Comment: Será que `data` **no** `es == "0"`, mira a ver el valor de data

Comment: ya he utilizado ="1" Y = "" y sigue printeando el error

Comment: @IvanDiazPerez Si no sabemos cual es el valor de `data`, no te podremos ayudar

Comment: @IvanDiazPerez Estás pasándole el `formData` que es un substring de 1 carácter (que en teoría si es vacío debería fallarte, y sino, estás cogiendo el carácter "&") Por lo que a mi parecer, si el `formFields` es un array con mas de un elemento, tu valor data = "&"

Comment: Después de  if (data == "0") { agregá console.log(data); a ver que sale en la consola del browser -boton derecho->inspeccionar elemento->tab consola